# iOS: How to use Redis library in iOS application

Tags: ios, iphone, redis

I was doing the research on REDIS, and found that there was some wrapper on the redis website for Objective C. 
So I tried exploring that wrapper. But the thing is there is little support for that wrapper, and it is a static file, with the actual source code being a c code. What I inferred from the wrapper was, it takes an ip and a port number and some db name and you send some values to that particular ip address. So I think it is again an http call to some server location.

Do we have any sample application/support for integrating Redis in our application.